# How can I add two Scroll views in a xml layout such that each scrollview take half of the height of the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I add two ScrollViews in an android XML-layout such that each scroll view takes half of the height of the layout?

[image]

Comment: if you have dynamic data then you can use two RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` as rootview then add two `ScrollView` as child and assign `android:layout_weight="1"` to both `ScrollView`

> **Note :** if you want your view scroll horizontally then use **`HorizontalScrollView`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!--add viw here-->
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!--add viw here-->
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Yeah Sure. I need some reputation in order to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a multiple way to do this. I am suggesting you one simple way.
try to add weightsum =2 inside parent layout. And devide layout with 1 like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2.0" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#0000FF" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#00FF00" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```